# How can I keep my search filters when I go back to a previous web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of contacts and I have a couple of dropdown boxes to filter my contacts list between "vendors" and "customers".

If I select any, "vendors", "Contacts"  and sort those located in "Ontario" and I have a 10 record list and I clicik one ofthe records to display all his info.

BUT now I want to go back to my 10 record list of contacts in "Ontario", how I do it to dont loose the sorted list? i dont want to start my search all over again, I wan to go back and find the 10 records form "Ontario".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just keep them in a `List<T>`?

Comment: Winforms? XAML? ASP.NET? We need more details, there are a hundred different ways you could have presented this interface to the user, and we're not mind readers.

Comment: Okay, I fixed your title and tags. Next time please be more detailed.

Comment: @ SpikeX   Thank you, I'll be more specific  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the search parameters in the URL, e.g.

```
http://example.com/search?select=vendors&location=Ontario
```

Another option is to store the last search in the session (used e.g. by Trac) or a cookie (used e.g. by Bugzilla) and re-use it if visiting the search page again. That prevents multiple searches at once, though.

Comment: I think using session or cookies would fit for these case,  do you ahve any exapmles that I can use as a guide?

Answer (score 0):

If you are navigating to a differnet page for the info and you want to come back to the previous page and see the search criteria you had, you should store it in some temp storage. HTTP is stateless.So we need some temp storage locations.

You may consider storing your Search criteria in `Session` variable / `cookies`. when the previous page loads, check for session/cookies for the last search criteria you saved and load results according to that.

**EDIT** : A simple example using session.

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
  public string Type{ set;get;}
  public string Location { set;get;}
  //other properties based on your scenario
}
```

Then before redirecting to the new page(info page) Set the values in to the session

```
var search=new SearchCriteria();
search.Type="Vendors";  //hard coded for example. you may replace with your form values
search.Location="Ontario";
Session["SearchCriteria"]=search;
Response.Redirect("info.aspx?id=someId");
```

And in the PageLoad event of this search page, check for session

```
if(Session["SearchCriteria"]!=null)
{
    var search=(SearchCriteria) Session["SearchCriteria"];
    //Now load the search based on this search criteria.
    // check for search.Location/search.Type
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code example taht I can use as a guide to store the search criteria in a session?

Comment: Thank you, I am coding right now, i'll let you know for sure. Thanks :)